# r - different result with boxplot/quantile function

Tags: r, boxplot, quantile

I have created a boxplot with the code

`boxplot(X,horizontal = TRUE, axes = FALSE, staplewex = 1, boxwex = 0.05)
text(x = boxplot.stats(X[,1])$stats, labels = boxplot.stats(X[,1])$stats, y = 1.04)`.

However, the results I get from the text/boxplot function are different from then of the `quantile(X[,1],0.25)` or `summarize(X)` functions. I think boxplot maybe uses other definitions. But I was confucsed by the boxplot documentation since it is not very readable. Maybe someone can explain the differences to me!

Thank you for your help!
Simon

Comment: The [help page for boxplot.stats](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/boxplot.stats.html) says "The two ‘hinges’ are versions of the first and third quartile, i.e., close to quantile(x, c(1,3)/4). The hinges equal the quartiles for odd n (where n <- length(x)) and differ for even n." the [quantile function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/quantile.html) has different methods for calculating quantiles, and for the only data I tested, `type=2` and `type=5` agree with boxplot.